# Getting the location of a Grid during runtime in codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf

I am in the codebehind file for a usercontrol.  In this user control I have a grid called GBoard.  I create one instance of this user control in my main XAML file and I name it GameBoard.  Now I am in the codebehind as I said earlier, and I want to get the X/Y position of GameBoard.  If I grab the Margin, all the values are set to 0.  If I do Canvas.GetTop(this) it comes back as NaN.  How do I grab these coordinates?  I don't think it's a bug in my code as everything works, its just I can't seem to grab the coordinates.

```
Position = new Point(Canvas.GetTop(GameBoard), Canvas.GetLeft(GameBoard));
```

gets NaN for values.

```
boardMargin = GameBoard.Margin;
```

boardMargin is 0,0,0,0 even though its positioned in the center of the screen.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.Board"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:UserControls"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid Name="GBoard">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            //lots of these
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            //lots of these
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

that's the user control.  I edited out the massive amount of col and row defs for space.

```
<Page x:Class="GUI.SGUI"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:UserControls"
  Title="SGUI" Height="1000" Width="1000">

    <Canvas x:Name="LetterCanvas">
        <controls:Board x:Name="GameBoard" Height="Auto" Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="164" Width="Auto"/>
    </Canvas>
</Page>
```

I found out that if I access the location from the main class then I can get the coordinates, if I access them from the user control's codebehind I can't.  So if I have to I can make something hacky, but I'd rather get the coordinates inside of the user control.

Comment: could your share you xaml, or any code how you generate the grid and it's parent/childs?

Comment: What kind of coordinates you want here? I mean about the relative control from which the coordinates are calculated, such as the Screen, the MainWindow or any other control?

Comment: I want the coordinates relative to the window. so after my recent additions of code, I want the Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="164" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your usercontrol needs access to the Canvas in order to get the GameBoard's position because the Canvas element in WPF uses absolute positioning.

Assuming that LetterCanvas will be the parent element of the GameBoard - try using this in the code behind for your GameBoard user control:

```
double xPosition = Canvas.GetLeft(this);
double yPosition = Canvas.GetTop(this);
```

NOTE: must call from method and not constructor.

Comment: `GetTop` is a static method, it's actually used to access some value of an attached property (in this case the attached property is `TopProperty`) (the same for Left, Right, ...)

Comment: Uhh are you sure that code compiles?  First it tells me that VisualTreeHelper needs a cast.  Then it says that I can't access the methods GetTop and GetLeft from an instance reference.  It says to qualify it with a type name instead.

Comment: BTW, you declare and assign the `letterCanvas` but it's not used at all. So what's the magic here?

Comment: Forgot to delete it after you pointed out that GetLeft() and GetTop() were static methods.

Comment: I actually wanna change that to a partially works.  It works if I call it from a method in the user control code-behind, but not if I call it from the constructor of the code-behind....

Comment: The reason it doesn't work in the constructor is because the object hasn't been constructed yet. **this** is going to be null. Is there a strong reason to have this code in the constructor?

Comment: Well I don't really mind having to make a second call, but really its code that I would like to be in the constructor for the sake of organization.

Answer (score -1):

using the **Grid** element somewhere in your design. It provides information about the location of your controls in a very straight-forward kind of way. It works like a smarter version of a dynamicly-sizing HTML table. You can retrive ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties of any row or column - or even of the entire grid itself if you want.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not seeing it.  I am looking through the class in the visual studio debugger and everything is set to 0s and NaNs.

Comment: try with Grid.ActualWidth

Comment: I checked, that's 0 in visual studio debugger as well.